# Can mouse-over tool tips be made only to pop up when the mouse moves?

Tags: discussion

Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about web development so this may be a browser thing rather than a Stack Exchange thing, but I thought it was worth asking.

When I am scrolling through the front page of SO using the "page down" key, if I happen to have the mouse in the middle of the page, every so often it ends up so that the mouse happens to be over a tag name or user name or something else that causes a pop up, which the blocks the thing I was trying to read.

Is there a way to make the mouse-over pop ups only pop up when I've actually moved the mouse over them, as opposed to moving them under the mouse?

(If it makes any difference I'm currently using Firefox 3.5.15 on Linux).

[Edited to add: this is not a duplicate of [Too many pop-ups on mouse-hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109077/too-many-pop-ups-on-mouse-hover) because I'm quite happy with the pop ups that exist, I just only want to see them if I actively hover my mouse over them.]

Comment: You could leave the mouse off to the side in all the empty white-space so that it doesn't hover over things when the page moves. But I'm assuming this is only JavaScript-related things because I don't believe browser tooltips will pop up via scrolling (they don't for me, only JS things).

Comment: Yes, I do realise I could move the mouse off to the side - it's just a very minor annoyance to have to make sure I have done so!

Comment: @Vicky if you want, I can userscript this. Remind me tomorrow or the day after :)

Comment: ... 3.5? Seriously?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, I have a busy life and upgrading my browser (the whole laptop needs upgrading really) is not top of my to do list by a long way.

Comment: @TimManishEarth, that would be cool - thank you!

Comment: You should use Chrome. It updates itself. Like 280 times a day.